# Mapping extended entities with multiple ID's in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, nhibernate-mapping, jta

I have implemented a db which is consisted of Article and Fruit tables, with the following specifications:

```
create table Fruit
(
ART_ID            bigint,
FRU_ID          bigint not null auto_increment,
FRU_FROZEN   varchar(15),
primary key(FRU_ID)
);

# Implemented

create table Article
(
ART_ID            bigint,
ART_NAME         varchar(10) not null,
ART_COST   varchar(10) not null,
primary key(ART_ID)
);
```

alter table Fruits add constraint FK_FRUIT_ARTICLE foreign key (ART_ID)
references Article (ART_ID) on delete restrict on update restrict;

and with following class entities :
Article.java

```
@Entity      
@Table(name = "Article")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Article implements Serializable
 {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ART_ID")
private Long id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ART_NAME")
private String name;

@Basic(optional = true)
@Column(name = "ART_COST")
private String cost;
```

//   constructors, getters and setters

Fruit.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Fruit")
public class Fruit extends Article{


@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "FRU_ID")
private long fruitID;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "FRU_FROZEN")
private String fruitFrozen;
```

// constructors, getters and setters

Now, my problem is how to have ID in Article and in Fruit, if I keep it this way, it throws me exception that sub-class must not contain IDClass because it will result with multiple ID's. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means what it says, an Entity cannot have two IDs.

Consider the operation

```
entityManager.find(Article.class, 1l);
```

How is it supposed to know which one to return if there are two articles (an article and a fruit) that both have id 1?

If your tables need to each have IDs, entity inheritance is not an appropriate solution.  Consider putting the common elements in an `@MappedSuperclass` instead.

Comment: If I define @MappedSuperClass that will mean that Article is abstract, and I don't want that to happen. Why can't I have two ID's in one entity, If I declare one instance of Article it will get ID1 and if I declare another instance of Fruit after, it will get ID2 and FRU_ID1. Why is it such a hard thing to figure out?

Comment: Because it leaves findById undefined.  If a fruit has two IDs, which one is hibernate supposed to use to find it?

Comment: Well, what about it's primary key? ART_ID in table Fruit is just a secondary key that will "bind" properties of Article to the instance of Fruit.

Comment: It just doesn't work, sorry.  That is not how Hibernate implements EntityInheritance.  To use EntityInheritance there must be a single ID that is unique among all subclasses.

Comment: Entity inheritance is almost *never* a usable solution if you have a designed database that you're trying to build a hibernate model up on top of, rather than creating a natural domain model in java and having the DB schema generated by the framework.

Comment: So I will have to define @MappedSuperClass over Article? There is nothing else I can do about, is it? Just one more note, if I declare Article class with MappedSuperclass annotation, then there is no exception whatsoever....

Comment: Also, now I will have to define every entity with the properties from Article entity, with JOINED inheritance.